# Is it okay to use pictures from another shutterstock account?

Tags: copyright, licensing

I want to use a bunch of images from [shutterstock](http://www.shutterstock.com/) on a (not yet published) website. I know somebody who has a company and a shutterstock account, which means they can download a fixed amount of 750 high quality pictures/vector artworks per month. They wouldn't mind if they download some pictures for me.

Can I use the pictures legally on my website when they are downloaded with another shutterstock account which is not used by me?

Answer (score 1):

**No**

Shutterstock's [licence](http://www.shutterstock.com/license) (standard or enhanced) does not give the right to sublicence - you must become a Shutterstock licencee to use the images.